# How to delete a button when it was clicked if the buttons were made by a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, button, tkinter, command

I want to add a function that destroys the button (and all higher/lower ones) when it is pressed, if it is not the target button.

I hope this clears it up a bit.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('The Game')
window.geometry('1000x850')
target = random.randint(1,10)
words = []
for j in range(1, 11):
    unit = "box" + str(j)
    words.append(unit)
a=0
lives = 3
for i in words:
    a = a + 1
    def btn_press(event):
        guess = event.widget['text']
        global lives
        lives -= 1
        lives_rem.config(text = 'Lives remaining: ' + str(lives))
        if guess == target:
            print('you win')
            window.destroy()
        elif lives == 0:
            print('you lose')
            window.destroy()
        elif guess > target:
            #in this case, the button pressed and all of the higher ones should be destroyed
            print('too high')
        elif guess < target:
            #in this case, the button pressed and all of the lower ones should be destroyed
            print('too low')
    i = tk.Button(window, text = a)
    i.config(height = '3', width = '6')
    i.bind('<Button-1>', btn_press)
    i.place(x = -50 + a * 70, y = 25)

lives_rem = tk.Label(window, text = "Lives remaining: " + str(lives), fg = 'red')
lives_rem.place(x = 800, y = 50)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What would be best is to edit this to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can copy/paste it and run it ourselves. Otherwise our answers will likely have errors/typos in them that *you* will then need to sort through.

Comment: You can use this [extra arguments trick](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html) to pass the ` btn_press()` callback function extra arguments (such as the `Button` being pressed — the variable `i` in your code).

Comment: If `i` is the variable used in the for loop, you should not reassign it to hold the reference of button.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, i use another variable in the actual code.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, really helpful! What would be the right way to then remove or destroy the button once i found its name?

Comment: Артем: You can use the [`place_forget()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method) widget method to make a widget (like a `Button`) disappear from the screen. It still exists just isn't visible. You can use `place()` again to make it reappear (if you kept a reference to it).

Answer (score 1):

You've changed your question since I first commented so that now you need to keep track of all the `Button`s created because you now want to "destroy" more than just the one clicked. In the code below, they're being stored in a new global `list` variable named `buttons`.

A single widget displayed with the `place()` geometry manager can be made to disappear using the `place_forget()` method. Combining that with the new `buttons` list makes it possible to also affect the visibility of the others in the `'<Button-1>'` event callback function as well.

Below is your code with modifications showing how to do that. Note that I also optimized a few other things as well as making it overall follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations a little more closely.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('The Game')
window.geometry('1000x850')

target = random.randint(1,10)
print('target:', target)
words = ["box" + str(j) for j in range(1, 11)]
a = 0
lives = 3

buttons = []  # Remember all Buttons.
for _ in words:
    a += 1

    def btn_press(event):
        global lives

        guess = event.widget['text']
        lives -= 1
        lives_rem.config(text='Lives remaining: ' + str(lives))
        if guess == target:
            print('you win')
            window.destroy()
        elif lives == 0:
            print('you lose')
            window.destroy()
        elif guess > target:
            # In this case, the button pressed and all of the higher ones
            # should be destroyed.
            event.widget.place_forget()
            print('too high')
            for btn in buttons:
                if btn['text'] > guess:
                    btn.place_forget()
        elif guess < target:
            # In this case, the button pressed and all of the lower ones should
            # be destroyed.
            event.widget.place_forget()  # Added MRM
            print('too low')
            for btn in buttons:
                if btn['text'] < guess:
                    btn.place_forget()


    btn = tk.Button(window, text=a)
    btn.config(height=3, width=6)
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', btn_press)
    btn.place(x=a*70 - 50, y=25)
    buttons.append(btn)

lives_rem = tk.Label(window, text="Lives remaining: " + str(lives), fg='red')
lives_rem.place(x=800, y=50)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out its easier than it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I added few lines to your code to make the `Button` destroy if it is not the target value.

1. I don't understand why you have function `btn_press()` inside the for block. It has created like 10 `btn_press()` functions. I guess you each button to have their own function, but trust me one is enough. So I put the function outside the `for` loop
2. I added `event.widget.destroy()` in two of the condition ( for high and for low ) so then it is no the target `Button` it gets `destroy()`.
3. Also, your approach is not good you can improve your code by a lot.

Here is your updated code.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('The Game')
window.geometry('1000x850')
target = random.randint(1,10)

words = []
for j in range(1, 11):
    unit = "box" + str(j)
    words.append(unit)

a=0
lives = 3


def btn_press(event):
        guess = event.widget['text']
        global lives
        lives -= 1
        lives_rem.config(text = 'Lives remaining: ' + str(lives))
        if guess == target:
            print('you win')
            Score['text'] = 'Score: You Win' 
            window.destroy()
        elif lives == 0:
            print('you lose')
            Score['text'] = 'Score: You Lose' 
            window.destroy()
        elif guess > target:
            #in this case, the button pressed and all of the higher ones should be destroyed
            Score['text'] = 'Score: Too High' 
            print('too high')
            event.widget.destroy()
        elif guess < target:
            #in this case, the button pressed and all of the lower ones should be destroyed
            Score['text'] = 'Score: Too Low' 
            print('too low')
            event.widget.destroy()

for i in words:
    a = a + 1
    i = tk.Button(window, text = a)
    i.config(height = '3', width = '6')
    i.bind('<Button-1>', btn_press)
    i.place(x = -50 + a * 70, y = 25)

lives_rem = tk.Label(window, text = "Lives remaining: " + str(lives), fg = 'red')
lives_rem.place(x = 800, y = 50)

Score = tk.Label(window, text = "Score: " )
Score.place(x = 400, y = 100 )

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear the first time, but i would like to change the color of the button pressed (would you still need a list or syncing them?). Since i also have a mac, maybe changing foreground color wouldn't be ideal, and instead deleting or destroying the button is the way to go. I found a way to get the name of the button pressed, but when i use the name (in the form of variable), it tells me that strings dont have the .config property

Comment: @АртемБрехин: I think you still not clear. The background color of a `Button` is not changeable on MacOS. if you mean you just want to change the color of the only button pressed then please make it more clear so I can edit my answer. And the string you are getting is probably the name of the widget, you need an object of the `Button`.

Comment: @АртемБрехин: I edited my answers as well let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly. do you know also how i could make all buttons from above get destroyed (if the box clicked is too high) or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, but then the code has to be reconstructed with different logic of saving buttons in a list so the buttons can be accessible with the index of the list.